# Transfer data from JavaScript client to C# server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my virtual shop site I need to send product data (single or array) to server. In a case when I work with ASPX and runat="server", I'm organizing OnClick event and delegate. Is it possible in JavaScript? Is there any working example?

Comment: Can you post some code? It's not very clear what you're describing.

Comment: what would you want to do with the data on the server? Process it and refresh the page?

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail? Maybe some code you have so far?

Comment: look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481811/how-to-call-c-sharp-button-click-method-from-javascript

Answer (score 2):

I would use a webmethod for that and call the webmethod from javascript. 
Here is a good tutorial how to do that.

http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assign your value/values to hidden field on the page using JS - then access it in code behind and do your job.