# Sorting when click on GridView Header cell

Tags: asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

I’m using asp.net GridView and I want to sort the grid when click on anywhere in the header cell not only the header text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add some javascript that launches a postpost back (see this question: for more information on doing so with javascript: [ASP.NET postback with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript)) and then in your post back, manually fire the gridview's sort event? (or maybe you can call the eventhandler directly in the post back function.