# ASP.NET postback via client side in IE

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, postback, client-side

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ASP.NET postback with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript)

I'm going to make a postback in my ASP.NET web app using a JavaScript function, I can easily make a postback and call a serverside function in firefox and chrome but there is no luck in IE! I've tested several ways, is is possible to make such an action in IE? is there any live demo? any sample?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

__dopostback('<%button.UniqueID'%>');