# How to postback server by JavaScript Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

```
namespace KetBanBonPhuong.Controls.Default
{
     public partial class SugFriends : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private string Uid;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["UId"] != null)
        {
            string value = Request.Cookies["UId"].Value;
            Uid = UserService.GetId_Cookie(value);
        }
        else
        {
            Uid = Session["Id"].ToString();
        }
        LoadListSuggest();
    }

    private void LoadListSuggest()
    {
        string str = "";
        List<RankByUser> list = new List<RankByUser>();
        list = RankByUserService.GetListRank(Uid);
        foreach (RankByUser rank in list)
        {
            str += "<li><div class=\"sug_acc\">"
                + "<a href=\"/" + rank.Link + ".aspx\"><img src=\"" + rank.Avatar + "\" alt=\"avatar\"/></a>"
                + "<a href=\"/" + rank.Link + ".aspx\" class=\"sug_name\">" + rank.LastName + " " + rank.FirstName + "</a>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<div class=\"rank\">"
                + "<a href=\"#\" title=\"Xem chi tiết\" class=\"num\">rank: " + rank.Rank + "</a>"
                + "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button mycoblue\">Kết bạn</a>"
                + "</div></li>";
        }
            ltrListSug.Text = str;
        }
    }
}`
```

It's a user control `SugFriends.ascx` being add in `Default.Master`

When I click `"a.button"` postback event to server?(I want to insert data to database, I used Sql server)

How to do it? Make tag a event `onclick` 'like' `LinkButton: Onclick()`?

Thanks for your helping! I found solution that problem! I used Ajax onclick for each tag a, event post Ajax.aspx, in here I can code work with database!

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use server-side controls with a Repeater.

Comment: You have an XSS vulnerability.

Comment: @SLaks I trust your comment, but can you expand further?

Comment: @SLaks The XSS vulnerability. How is this method vulnerable?

Comment: @danyim: Create an account with a first name of `<script>alert('XSS')</script>`

Comment: @SLaks I want to user for each tag a, if not via Javascript, how to other way Can I user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `onclick="(javascript:__doPostBack('','');"` attribute to the `<a>` tag to perform a postback via Javascript. Like this:

```
            + "<a href=\"#\" class=\"button mycoblue\" onclick=\"(javascript:__doPostBack('','');\">Kết bạn</a>"
```

[More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript)

---

Response to comment:

Try creating a button on the page
`<asp:Button ID="btnPlaceHolder" Visible="False" runat="server" />` and then do what I said in this solution but instead use  `__doPostBack('<%=btnPlaceHolder.UniqueID %>', '')`

From there, you can use the method block
`Private Sub btnPlaceHolder_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnPlaceHolder.Click` to run the code you want on postback.

Comment: About code C#, Where I can write for onclick() like LinkButton protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {code here}

Comment: Updated my solution to answer your comment.

Comment: Problem is I have many buttons like that(tag a in foreach loop), I can't great all by handle.