# How do I make an ASP.NET postback-confirmation dialog with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am using the below code to get a Jquery UI popup, but its not returning the value and popup box is closing

I need when i click on button it has to work as confirmation box..!

Code :

```
<style type="text/css" >
        .ui-widget-header, .ui-widget-content
    { color: red !important;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('You are going to Lock the Record.<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirm..?',
            buttons: { "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }, "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
            }
        });

        $(function fn() {
            $('#Button1').click(function (e) {
                return $myDialog.dialog('open');

            });
        });
    });
</script>


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return fn() onclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Comment: You have missed a double quote(") for OnClientclick="return fn()"

Comment: sorry ! its typo error even though its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function fn() {

 });
```

U have a dom ready function inside another one.u need to remove the above block...

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('You are going to Lock the Record.<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirm..?',
            buttons: { "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }, "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
            }
        });
            $('<%=Button1.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
                $myDialog.dialog('open');
                return false;

            });
    });
```

I hope this is right.

Comment: i have removed.. its not woking

Answer (score 0):

.dialog('open') will always return straight away it will not wait for user action.

You need to change your code to tigger a postback for the Button1 control. Instead of relying on return values.

See here for info on triggering postback [ASP.NET postback with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript)

**Edit**

```
<style type="text/css" >
        .ui-widget-header, .ui-widget-content
    { color: red !important;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('You are going to Lock the Record.<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirm..?',
            buttons: { "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

__doPostBack("<%=Button1.ClientID %>","");

            }, "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
            }
        });

        $(function fn() {
            $('#Button1').click(function (e) {
                return $myDialog.dialog('open');

            });
        });
    });
</script>


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" Text="Button" OnClientClick="return fn()" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Comment: I got it what you are saying?Can you please explain me in more clear

Comment: Hi, I have updated your code I think that should work.  I am not at a pc where I could test that but pretty sure it should work. let me know.

Comment: Hi Zonder.. i am trying the same code in master and child page.. i am getting error object expected 
$(function fn() {
            $('#Button1').click(function (e) {
                return $myDialog.dialog('open');

            });
        });
the above function is not executing

Comment: because your button is running at the server it's name isn't Button1 use <%=Button1.ClientID %> in place to get it's true id

Comment: sorry to come back again here ...i dont have reputation point to chat 
i have tried the same code by placing in content page and copied the style sheet and script ta to master page.. then agin the same error came ...!
i used <%=Button1.ClientID %> only and the button id also Button1 only.

Comment: The line __doPostBack("<%=Button1.ClientID %>",""); performs the button postback your code in the code behind should be executing

Answer (score 0):

it's hard to understand the structure of your dom.

but i will give you a working solution

`<div id="someDialog">some controls or text or whatever you want to show./div>// add it to your page.`

then use Jquery and Jquery UI libraries, put it into head tag

```
$(function(){
$('#someDialog').dialog({ autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirm..?',
            buttons: { "OK": function () {
                if(confirm("are you sure you want to close the dialog))
                     $(this).dialog("close");

            }, "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            });


 $('#Button1').click(function (e) {
                $('#someDialog').dialog('open');

            }); // without return statement. 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the asp.net button rendered with ID 'Button1' in HTML output? If yes, you can try following code (amended your code)

Code :

```
<style type="text/css" >
        .ui-widget-header, .ui-widget-content
    { color: red !important;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var $myDialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('You are going to Lock the Record.<br/>Click OK to confirm.  Click Cancel to stop this action.')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirm..?',
            buttons: { "OK": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }, "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");

            }
            }
        });

         $('#Button1').click(function (e) {
               $myDialog.dialog('open');
               e.preventDefault();      
          });
      });
</script>


<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Comment: even i tried this but same result at the time of load the confirmation is appearing and closing

Comment: I have edit the code slightly. `$('#Button1').click` need not to return thing. See this [link](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) for more details.

Comment: Thank you .. i hope its working .. but post back also working the same how to perform the same function at client side not going to server side ?

Comment: You can add `e.preventDefault();` inside you `$('#Button1').click` handler after displaying the dialog. I have updated the code, which should prevent a postback

Comment: Yes / No is just closing the dialog.but when i click on Yes on the Jquery UI , the server code have to work ..?

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS Class delete to control, then apply the jquery confirm dialog:

```
$('.delete').click(function () {
          return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this record?'); 
    });
```