# Call a BackEnd-Method from FrontEnd written in BackEnd

Tags: asp.net

its a bit complicatet to explain, but I hope I can make it clear:

In my BackEnd I have an StringBuilder in which I write HTML-Code for the FrontEnd and assign it to a Div.InnerHTML to show. Now in this code I must have a possibiliy to call a BackEnd-Method like I would normaly do with a LinkButton, but a LinkButton isn't a LinkButton when it's shown in HTML so I cant work with  here.

A bit of code:

```
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendLine("<td>");
 sb.AppendLine("Test ");
//Here I need to insert a Button that calls a BackEnd-Method From the FrontEnd but Written in BackEnd
 sb.AppendLine("</td>");
 div.innerHTML = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Postback with javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8762320/284240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend attaching a CSS class name via the `CssClass` property of your dynamically created button.

Then have jQuery handle the click of the button via event delegation using the `on ()` function.

Read [jQuery on() function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for more information.

Once you have jQuery handing the event client side, then you have several choices of interacting with the server (__dopostback, ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods, ASP.NET Web API, asmx web services, WCF, etc.).