# How to link up ASP.Net page to code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have a list:

```
<ul class="question">
    <li>eBook Reader</li>
    <li>Normal Mobile</li>
    <li>Smartphone</li>
    <li>PC / Laptop</li>
    <li>Landline Telephone</li>
    <li>Tablet</li>
    <li>Games Console</li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="button next">Continue</a>
```

A user is able to click any of the `<li>` items and it will add a class of selected to it. When they click continue, it needs to run at a method on the server which will take in the index of the `<li>` selected and do something with it.

The trouble is I've no idea how to do this with .aspx pages. I tried having this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="ContinueClick" Text="Continue" CssClass="button next" />
```

Instead of the existing `<a>` tag but I can't seem to be able to pull anything meaningful out of it.

Comment: Is a javascript/jquery solution also viable for you or do you need to store the selected items in a sort of collection for later use in another page?

Comment: @Serv I need to make a call back to the server every time they click continue. I'll save that info in the database and then move on to another continue on the same page.

Comment: if you want to add the css classes for selected /notselected clientside, here is a jsfiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/qFeBA/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should be a `radio button list`, and then take the selected value from there instead of using a list.  Take a look at this [link](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/radiobuttonlist-example-how-to-use.html) to see how to use a radio button list.

I think when you want a user to single select from a group, then a `radio button list` is the correct option.  When you want a multi-select, then use a `checkbox list`.

The code will be similar to this...

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="questions" runat="server">  
    <asp:ListItem>eBook Reader</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem>Normal Mobile</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem>Smartphone</asp:ListItem>  
    <asp:ListItem>PC / Laptop</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem>Landline Telephone</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem>Tablet</asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem>Games Console</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>


protected void ContinueClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)   
{   
  //questions.SelectedItem.ToString();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `Id` and `runat="server"` on the elements that you would like to access on the server-side with their attributes and css-class.

You can also solve this by adding radio buttons, instead of a list.

Another solution to your issue might be a hidden control that holds the id of the selected element.

Answer (score -1):

You can manually trigger postbacks to ASP.NET from JavaScript like this [ASP.NET postback with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript)