# onclick and onclientclick webmethod executed after onclick

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to set a variable on using a webmethod (`.asmx`)

The button is using `onclick` to call a server side method and `onclientclick` to call a javascript ajax which calls the webmethod.

I need the javascript code to be fully executed before the onclick server end method is called, but it seems as though the ajax call is not fully being executed before the postback is being made.

The alert is called before postback however the webmethod is being called after the postback.  I need the variable to be set from the webmethod before the postback is done.  I have tried returning a false from the javascript but then postback isnt being done at all.

I am using Masterpages in asp.net.  Also I have a similar function in another project which works fine, the only difference is in this one I'm using a MasterPage.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button ID="btnAddRegistration" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="btn-sm btn-default" runat="server"
        CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>"
        onclick="btnAddRegistration_Click"
        OnClientClick='<%# "getSetContactID(\"" + Container.DataItemIndex + "\")" %>'
        Text="Add &#010;Registration" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript (call to webmethod)

```
 function getSetContactID(rowIndex) {

    var CellValue, cell, dataItemIndex;
    var table = document.getElementById('<%=gvContactSearch.ClientID %>');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService1.asmx/setContactIDgvContact",
        data: '{DataItemIndex: "' + rowIndex + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: alert(rowIndex), <--this gets called before postback
        failure: function (response) {alert(response.d);}

        })
 }
```

Webservice method

```
 [WebMethod]
        public string setContactIDGV1(int DataItemIndex){
           classDetails.gV1DataItemIndex = DataItemIndex; 
           return "";
        }
```

Comment: Try this: Return always false from client click getSetContactID method and in  ajax success event explicitly invoke button postback method-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305954/asp-net-postback-with-javascript

Comment: try to set **async: false** property in jquery ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is a classic race-condition scenario.

By default an AJAX call is asynchronous, so when you fire an AJAX call the JS code block logically comes to an end, and the next sequential event is fired, in this case your server side event. It's then a race between the function that the AJAX code has executed and your server-side onclick event. The way I see it you have a few options:

1. Call your web service method inside your server-side on click method
2. Prevent the default element action inside the JS block (`event.preventDefault`), and hook something up inside the AJAX `success` method that finishes the sequence
3. Set the `async: false` option on the AJAX call

Comment: async: false did it for me!